# jQuery reverse ordering of .each()

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get the following animation to play in reverse. The initial drop-down of the sub-menus is fine, however i'm trying to reverse it when it is no longer being hovered over (So that Product 4 fades out first, then 3, then 2 etc.)

HTML

```
<div class="postit-surround">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="postit">
                <div class="pin">
                    <img src="assets/pin.png">
                </div>
                <div class="postit-title">
                    Products
                </div>
                <div class="corner-peel">
                    <img src="assets/corner-flick-cyan.png">
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <div class="navigation-dropdown">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    Products Page 1
                </li>
                <li>
                    Products Page 2
                </li>
                <li>
                    Products Page 3
                </li>
                <li>
                    Products Page 4
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
div.navigation-dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: -5px;
}
div.navigation-dropdown > ul {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    width: 140px;
}
div.navigation-dropdown > ul > li {
    padding: 10px 10px 20px 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    background-color: #aaaaaa;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition:    -moz-transform 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition:      -o-transform 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition:     -ms-transform 0.3s ease-out;
    transition:         transform 0.3s ease-out;
    cursor: pointer;
}
div.navigation-dropdown> ul> li:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition:    -moz-transform 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition:      -o-transform 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition:     -ms-transform 0.3s ease-out;
    transition:         transform 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

JS

```
$("div.navigation-dropdown").children().children().hide();

$("div.postit-surround").hover(function(){

    var offset = 200;
    function dropdown(x){
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(x).fadeIn(500);
        },$(x).index() * offset)
    };

    $(this).find("div.navigation-dropdown > ul > li").each(function(){
        dropdown(this);
    });
}, function(){

    var offset = 200;

    function dropup(y){
    setTimeout(function() {
            $(y).fadeOut(500);
        },$(y).index() * offset)
    };

    $($("div.navigation-dropdown > ul > li").get().reverse()).each(function() {
        dropup(this);
    });
})
```

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/vVZy3/

I have seen a few example that people have pointed out in other questions, but none have worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're triggering the event in the right order using `.reverse()`, your problem is the timeout definition, which should also be inverted:

use `(4-$(y).index()) * offset`

instead of `$(y).index() * offset`

cf. http://jsfiddle.net/vVZy3/1/

P.S.: You may want to compute the list length instead of hard-coding the 4 as I did here.

Comment: Great! Works like a charm. I had a feeling it was something to do with the timeout after the amount of time I spent on the trigger. Thanks!

Comment: Answer is perfect but just try to slide the mouse over it... `Products Page 4` is not hiding... Am not sure about the problem...

Comment: Yes, I'm currently trying to solve the multiple issues with fast on-off hover movement. I'm thinking something along the lines of $.finish() might work, maybe a $.stop(), whilst adding the two "dropdown" and "dropup" functions to a queue to check whether the queue is working currently before running the next function

Comment: I managed to solve the fast on-off issues with increasing the speed of the functions slightly, and by using an IF statement to check whether the elements are or are not visible before running the function to move the elements. See the fiddle (Flashes in here, not on site though): [link](http://jsfiddle.net/dN5Pe/)

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>***[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R6kQ7/)***</kbd>
*Javascript Code*

```
var totalLI = $("div.navigation-dropdown ul li").length;

$("div.postit").hover(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("div.navigation-dropdown ul li").each(function () {
        $(this).fadeIn($(this).index() * offset);
    });
    blockFadeOut = false;
}, function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("div.navigation-dropdown ul li").each(function () {
        $(this).fadeOut((totalLI - $(this).index()) * offset);
    });
});
```

[Your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vVZy3/3/)

---

<kbd>***[Fiddle using stop() which solves the mouse slide problem](http://jsfiddle.net/R6kQ7/1/)***</kbd>

Hope it helps.....